# AngularJS way to use a dropdown menu

Tags: angularjs

I have the following items:

```
<span ng-click="ui.toggleShow('company')" class="dropdown-trigger">
    <i class="icon-building"></i>
</span>
<span ng-click="ui.toggleShow('notifications')" class="dropdown-trigger">
    <i class="icon-info"></i>
</span>
...
<dropdown-element ng-show=...>
```

The ui.toggleShow function is in the following object in the Controller:

```
$scope.ui = {
  show: 'nothing',
  toggleShow: function(elem) {
    if (elem === $scope.ui.show) {
      $scope.ui.show = 'nothing';
    } else {
      $scope.ui.show = elem;
    }
  }
};
```

This part works just like it should, but I can only "toggle" my dropdown elements, when I click on this span tags.

I tried to use this `ui.toggleShow` in parent tags, but that (obviously) overwrites this ui.show property all the time, so even if I click on the right tag it becomest 'nothing' because I clicked the parent.

I try not to use any jQuery in the site, or other DOM manipulation.

How should I change my code to open the dropdown elements by clicking these span-s, and close them by clicking anywhere else? (in an Angular way)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the blur directive:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngBlur

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this only works on some DOM elements, like 'input'. For me, this should work on a 'div' element, or better if I could add this to the body.